# php - mysql_real_escape_string and varchar issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I'm using mysql_query in php and my problem is, when I pass a string with mysql_real_escape_string, it returns no results. when I remove the mysql_real_escape_string function, it works perfectly. This is my code:

```
public function select_user($user) {  
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '".mysql_real_escape_string($user)."'";
 return $this->query($sql);
}
```

note that $this->query is a function for querying the statement.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: What are you expecting it to do? Check usernames that contain the string anywhere? You're missing `%` signs for that. Also, don't use the `mysql_` extensions, as mentioned above.

Comment: Well I think I must go with MySQLi or PDO....That seems a better option...Thanks!

Comment: Have you compared what the `$sql` variable actually looks like with the version that works and the one that doesn't work. Seeing the difference between them might give you a clue about what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

most likely there is no mysql connection established for the mysql_* functions and thus mysql_real_escape_string returns an empty string.

You have to use whatever formatting/binding facilities allowed by the API you're using for your `query()` method.